# A href to open page with jquery and make certain div expanded

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle, accordion

Asking for help.

We use this script on our site's FAQ page:
http://jsfiddle.net/ApCGU/

By default divs p_9, p_10, p_11, p_12.. are collapsed. 
Can i write the a href in a way that a certain div is already as expanded when user gets to page:

Current code:

```
<a href="faq.aspx">FAQ</a>
```

Wished:

```
<a href="faq.aspx#p_9">FAQ question 9</a>
<a href="faq.aspx#p_10">FAQ question 10</a>
```

Just adding the anchor doesn't appear to be working here.

Comment: You could probably add a function to open the accordion when the anchor receives focus...would that work?

Comment: why cant u use body onload?

Comment: You can see my answer for working example

Comment: horace:do u need the same function to be working after page loads?or simply at startup?

Comment: @sree 
yes it should also work afterwards, meaning it should be possible to close that div... I'm just trying out Hüseyin B's solution, it doesn't want to collapse for me..yet
I am really grateful for all the replies so far - Stack community is just wonderful!

Comment: I have updated demo and code in order to use toggle on demo page. Forgot to add that. Check my updated demo pages on my answer

Comment: @horace:then i think if u just call on startup,it does the job at page load..after that onclick u just call that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get hash from url and toggle slide by using that like;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;// Returns e.g. "#p_9"
    $(hash).slideToggle();
});
```

Here is **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nb29R/9/)** for code part, and here is **[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nb29R/9/show/#p_9)**(Press ctrl+f5 when you goto demo page in order to see it is working).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value of the div that should open to the page via a URL parameter (or localStorage) and then display the div when the page loads, or after a short delay.

http://jsfiddle.net/philsinatra/8ppqg/1/

```
/**
 * pass this value as a URL parameter or through localStorage/cookie
 * @type {String}
 */
var defaultOpen = '9'; 

$(document).ready(function() {
  var t = setTimeout(function() {
    P_Expand(defaultOpen);
  }, 1000);
})
```

Comment: when loads,it is getting called,after that it is not calling the functino..did u notice?

Comment: Your button functionality could be a little cleaner, it's probably contributing to the issues. I did an updated version of the click handler that works. http://jsfiddle.net/philsinatra/8ppqg/2/